# calling an object with a numeric name

Tags: r

I loaded some data in R and mistakenly named it as 86. Now when I want to call the data frame I end up with the number 86 instead of my data set. Is there a way to call the data set rather than the number 86? Also, is there a way to change the name of the data so it is no longer a number? Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use backticks:

```
"86" <- data.frame(a = "meow", b = "wouf")
> `86`
#      a    b
# 1 meow wouf
```

To change the name of your data frame, simply *assign* (`<-`) data from `86` to `df` and *remove* (`rm`) the original `86`

```
df <- `86`; rm(`86`) 
> df
#      a    b
# 1 meow wouf
```

Because of [*copy-on-modify*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759117/what-exactly-is-copy-on-modify-semantics-in-r-and-where-is-the-canonical-source), this will not allocate memory for `df`.

```
> "86" <- data.frame(a = "meow", b = "wouf"); tracemem(`86`)
# [1] "<0x3936b28>"
> df <- `86`; tracemem(df)
# [1] "<0x3936b28>"
```