# Confusion with scoping / parameter passing in R

Tags: r

Hi ran the following lines and was a bit surprised. Confusion inline:

Ok so I create a list:

```
> x<-list()
```

assign 1 to be an element indexed by "a"

```
> x$a<-1
```

I ask to see what is in x

```
> x
$a
[1] 1
```

yup so far so good

next I declare a function that will take list that is passed to it and like the assignment to index "a" I'll just assign to index "b" value 2

```
> foo<-function(xx) {
+   xx["b"]<-2
+   print(xx)
+ }
```

I call the function with x - I like what I see
Now my thinking is that the list object got passed (by reference as in C when you do &x) and it was destructively modified

```
> foo(x)
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 2
```

Now outside the body of the function I print x -- but surprised not to see b

```
> x
$a
[1] 1

>
```

I read scooping and parameter passing docs but couldn't figure this out. Is the list being deep or shallow copied before the function body is invoked?

Comment: You need to either `assign` or `x <- foo(x)`

Comment: so you're saying I would need to return the modified list and re-assign it. The would not be an elegant solution because I'm writing a graph walker ... let me look at assign. Thanks again

Comment: `Now my thinking is that the list object got passed (by reference as in C)`. First time I heard C passes by reference. BTW, R is a *functional* programming language. Arguments of a function are copied and their modifications are not kept outside the function scope.

Comment: @nicola I meant forced to pass by reference like &a

Comment: @user975917 don't get your last comment. Arguments in C are *always* passed by value. You maybe want to say that you can pass (by value of course) a reference, but that doesn't change the fact that C doesn't pass by reference. Anyway, why did you think that R functions modify their arguments? Even this info is so wrong that I wonder where you got that belief.

Comment: @nicola you are right -- what I meant was u can pass the original object (reference) by passing (by copy) the address of the object

Comment: @nicola -- so my question is ... say you have a large graph structure that you wish to modify say splice something in -- does that mean you I have to do a complete duplication each time?

Comment: This is another question. If you intend to build graph structures, rely on specific packages (like `igraph`) that let you build graphs efficiently. Since you are still learning, I'd suggest you not to think about how and when R copies objects, since it might be too advanced at this stage. In your example, you can simply try `x<-foo(x)` if you want to modify `x`.

Comment: @nicola ture, actually I'm trying to use the R data structures in classical CS algorithms to find out precisely what is happening under the hood

Comment: @nicola so for example I'd like to emulate a hash table, linked list, tree etc using R lists -- the idea is to learn

Comment: @nicola -- anyhow I solved my actual problem using a<-foo(a) but it does not seem a very elegant solution  for now -- thanks again

Comment: I understand why you would do that, but IMO it's not necessarily worthwhile. R is used for manipulating data, not so much to develop classical software with all classical data structures. Tabular data fits well into a data.frame, that is what you would use 90% of the time. Never used a linked list in years with R. Why don't you work the other way around and learn what kind of native data structure R has and what they are used for?

Comment: `does not seem a very elegant solution` why not? Important, don't try to import other languages' logic into R. R is not intended to implement tree structures and double linked list (while actually internally any R object is a double linked list), since these are low-level programming structures. R is a high level language aimed to statistical analysis.

Comment: @nicola yes I understand that -- trying to push R to the limits -- next step is writing C code based R packages -- but trying to understand performance. I'm pretty fluent in classical R use cases melt, cast, data frames, etc. -- but trying to push my knowledge

Comment: @antoine-sac totally understand -- trying to push the envelope to better understand R

Comment: You seem very curious and willing to learn, so I hope you don't take what I'm about to say in the wrong way. I doubt you are "fluent in classical R", as if you were, you wouldn't have been surprised by the behaviour reported in your question. Step more on the R basics and soon you'll discover how powerful R can be, especially if you intend (as it seems) to extend it with C code. But before flying, learn to walk and run. This link http://adv-r.had.co.nz/C-interface.html#calling-c can give you a glimpse on the internal nature of R objects and it's a start to write R/C code.

Answer (score 1):

From [1]:

> The semantics of invoking a function in R argument are call-by-value.

Which means the argument is evaluated in the calling frame and deep-copied to the functions evaluation environment. (Only exception are default parameters, also see [1] for details.)

[1] https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Argument-evaluation

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759117/what-exactly-is-copy-on-modify-semantics-in-r-and-where-is-the-canonical-source) discusses R's copy-on-modify mechanism in more detail; Hadley's explanation of functions [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html) contains an example very similar to yours (look under section 'Return Values'). The short summary is that conceptually (and for all practical purposes from a user's perspective), R  *always* passes parameters *by value*. Behind the scenes, an interpreter might avoid this if it can deduce that is safe to do so, but an application programmer cannot and should not make any assumptions.