# Duplicating/assigning a data.table object to a new Robject

Tags: r, data.table, rstudio

I'm testing a function that I'm writing, which uses a data.table object. Before, I "duplicate objects" by creating a new object and assigning the object I wanted to duplicate/copy to the new one like this one:

```
# my data.table object
unFildata <- vcfLoad_datatable("test.vcf")

# copy/duplicate unFildata to dataIn
dataIn <- unFildata
```

Then, I do some operation on dataIn like this:

```
# do some operation to replace some rows of GT column with NA
dataIn[!(GT %in% c("0/1", "0/0", "1/1")), GT := NA]
```

I looked at the unique values of GT of the `dataIn` object and the output are like this:

```
# unique GT
unique(dataIn$GT)

# output
[1] "0/1" "0/0" NA    "1/1"
```

Then, I check for the unique values of `unFildata`, which I did not use except for assigning to `dataIn`:

```
# unique GT of unFildata
unique(unFildata$GT)

# output 
[1] "0/1" "0/0" NA    "1/1"
```

So basically, I had the same output. I rerun loading the file and look at the unique values again of `unFildata` and it is:

```
unFildata <- vcfLoad_datatable("test.vcf")
unique(unFildata$GT)
[1] "0/1" "0/0" "0/4" "1/3" "1/2" "1/1" "0/2" "./." "0/3" "3/3" "2/2"
```

It seems like the `dataIn` and `unFildata` are linked. Is this a data.table behaviour?

Or is this an Rstudio thing, I remember that the column numbers of data.table objects does not change in the environment panel of Rstudio when performing operations on data.table?

And how do you create a copy of a data.table object?

Comment: Use `DT2 <- copy(DT)`.

Comment: Is this a data.table property? Like the linking of object and preventing multiple copies which can possibly eat up RAM?

Comment: Yeah, it's tied up with that. R copies an object as soon as it can recognize that it has been modified, which is arguably too often for large objects like tables. Data.table makes many modifications without triggering such a copy. The only reference I know for this is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759117/what-exactly-is-copy-on-modify-semantics-in-r-and-where-is-the-canonical-source

Comment: seems like a long read to fully understand that one. Why not put your comments to answer =D

Comment: Ah right, here's the longer answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10225098/ I can't close it but someone else could.