# Copy-on-modify semantic on a vector does not append in a loop. Why?

Tags: r, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

This question sounds to be partially answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759117/what-exactly-is-copy-on-modify-semantics-in-r-and-where-is-the-canonical-source) but this is not enough specific to me. I would like to understand better when an object is updated by reference and when it is copied.

The simpler example is vector growing. The following code is blazingly inefficient in R because the memory is not allocated before the loop and a copy is made at each iteration.

```
  x = runif(10)
  y = c() 

  for(i in 2:length(x))
    y = c(y, x[i] - x[i-1])
```

Allocating the memory enable to reserve some memory without reallocating the memory at each iteration. Thus this code is drastically faster especially with long vectors.

```
  x = runif(10)
  y = numeric(length(x))

  for(i in 2:length(x))
    y[i] = x[i] - x[i-1]
```

And here comes my question. Actually when a vector is updated it *does* move. There is a copy that is made as shown below.

```
a = 1:10
pryr::tracemem(a)
[1] "<0xf34a268>"
a[1] <- 0L
tracemem[0xf34a268 -> 0x4ab0c3f8]:
a[3] <-0L
tracemem[0x4ab0c3f8 -> 0xf2b0a48]:
```

But in a loop this copy does not occur

```
y = numeric(length(x))
for(i in 2:length(x))
{
   y[i] = x[i] - x[i-1]
   print(address(y))
}
```

Gives

```
[1] "0xe849dc0"
[1] "0xe849dc0"
[1] "0xe849dc0"
[1] "0xe849dc0"
[1] "0xe849dc0"
[1] "0xe849dc0"
[1] "0xe849dc0"
[1] "0xe849dc0"
[1] "0xe849dc0"
```

I understand why a code is slow or fast as a function of the memory allocations but I don't understand the R logic. Why and how, for the same statement, in a case the update is made by reference and in the other case the update in made by copy. In the general case how can we know what will happen.

Comment: "a" is integer and you are assigning a "double"  (0); hence the copy made (an "integer" to "double" vector coercion)

Comment: Good catch. I edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I complete the @MikeH. awnser with this code

```
library(pryr)

x = runif(10)
y = numeric(length(x))
print(c(address(y), refs(y)))

for(i in 2:length(x))
{
  y[i] = x[i] - x[i-1]
  print(c(address(y), refs(y)))
}

print(c(address(y), refs(y)))
```

The output shows clearly what happened

```
[1] "0x7872180" "2"        
[1] "0x765b860" "1"        
[1] "0x765b860" "1"        
[1] "0x765b860" "1"        
[1] "0x765b860" "1"        
[1] "0x765b860" "1"        
[1] "0x765b860" "1"        
[1] "0x765b860" "1"        
[1] "0x765b860" "1"        
[1] "0x765b860" "1" 
[1] "0x765b860" "2"
```

There is a copy at the first iteration. Indeed because of Rstudio there are 2 refs. But after this first copy `y` belongs in the loops and is not available into the global environment. Then, Rstudio does not create any additional refs and thus no copy is made during the next updates. `y` is updated by reference. On loop exit `y` become available in the global environment. Rstudio creates an extra refs but this action does not change the address obviously.

Answer (score 9):

This is covered in Hadley's Advanced R book. In it he says (paraphrasing here) that whenever 2 or more variables point to the same object, R will make a copy and then modify that copy. Before going into examples, one important note which is also mentioned in Hadley's book is that when you're using `RStudio`

> the environment browser makes a reference to every object you create on the command line.

Given your observed behavior, I'm assuming you're using `RStudio` which we will see will explain why there are actually 2 variables pointing to `a` instead of 1 like you might expect.

The function we'll use to check how many variables are pointing to an object is `refs()`. In the first example you posted you can see:

```
library(pryr)
a = 1:10
refs(x)
#[1] 2
```

This suggests (which is what you found) that 2 variables are pointing to `a` and thus any modification to `a` will result in R copying it, then modifying that copy.

Checking the `for loop` we can see that `y` always has the same address and that `refs(y) = 1` in the for loop. `y` is not copied because there are no other references pointing to `y` in your function `y[i] = x[i] - x[i-1]`:

```
for(i in 2:length(x))
{
  y[i] = x[i] - x[i-1]
  print(c(address(y), refs(y)))
}

#[1] "0x19c3a230" "1"         
#[1] "0x19c3a230" "1"         
#[1] "0x19c3a230" "1"         
#[1] "0x19c3a230" "1"         
#[1] "0x19c3a230" "1"         
#[1] "0x19c3a230" "1"         
#[1] "0x19c3a230" "1"         
#[1] "0x19c3a230" "1"         
#[1] "0x19c3a230" "1"
```

On the other hand if introduce a *non-primitive* function of `y` in your `for loop` you would see that address of `y` changes each time which is more in line with what we would expect:

```
is.primitive(lag)
#[1] FALSE

for(i in 2:length(x))
{
  y[i] = lag(y)[i]
  print(c(address(y), refs(y)))
}

#[1] "0x19b31600" "1"         
#[1] "0x19b31948" "1"         
#[1] "0x19b2f4a8" "1"         
#[1] "0x19b2d2f8" "1"         
#[1] "0x19b299d0" "1"         
#[1] "0x19b1bf58" "1"         
#[1] "0x19ae2370" "1"         
#[1] "0x19a649e8" "1"         
#[1] "0x198cccf0" "1"
```

Note the emphasis on *non-primitive*. If your function of `y` is primitive such as `-` like: `y[i] = y[i] - y[i-1]` R can optimize this to avoid copying.

**Credit to @duckmayr for helping explain the behavior inside the for loop.**

Comment: This might have something to do with the value of the `named` field of the underlying object being set to 1, as in the situation described in [Section 1.1.2 of the R Internals Manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-ints.html#Rest-of-header), "where in principle two copies of [a variable] exist for the duration of the computation... *but for no longer*" (emphasis added).

Comment: @duckmayr, I think you're right. If I use a non-primitive function it copies then modifies

Comment: Ok I understand the point related to Rstudio that create two variables pointing to the same object. However I don't understand the loop. If `=` is a primitive that can be optimized then `y[i] = lag(y)[i]` should also be optimized?

Comment: @JRR good catch, I'm assuming it's because -  is a primitive. Just updated my answer

Comment: @MikeH. I think I got it. You wrote `lag(y)` not `lag(x)`. `lag(y)` create a second ref  into `lag`. At the update time there are 2 refs. But at the print time there is only 1 ref remaining since the `y` into `lag` does not exist anymore. If you change your code for `lag(x)[i]` there are no longer any copy. The loop is optimized and Rstudio does not create extra refs in the loop. Is that possible?

Comment: @MikeH. also I ran the code in a terminal without Rstudio and `a[1] <- 2`created a copy... even with `refs(a)` equal to 1

Comment: @JRR, apologies again for the update. I think the way it works is that your original for loop did not create an extra reference to `y` so it was not copied. If you use a non-primitive like `lag(y)` this creates an extra reference to `y` so it is copied. On the other hand if you use a primitive like `y[i] - y[i-1]`, this is optimized and does not copy `y`.

Comment: @JRR, try `a[1] <- 2L`