# Replacement functions in R

Tags: r

I read Advanced R by Hadley Wickham on his book's website. I found a question about replacement functions in R. The following result is given according to his book.

```
library(pryr)
x <- 1:10
address(x)
#> [1] "0x103945110"

x[2] <- 7L
address(x)
#> [1] "0x103945110"
```

He supposed that the address of x won't change if we just replace the second element of x. However, when I do this, the physical address of x actually changed. So, anybody tell me why?

Comment: Did you run that exact code?

Comment: Note that if you used `7` instead of `7L` that is a change to the code.

Comment: I can replicate the issue. I get an address change, running 64-bit R 3.4.0 on macOS Sierra, `pryr` version 0.1.3.

Comment: Here too, x86_64-w64-mingw32, R 3.5.0, pryr 0.1.4, found source here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#replacement-functions

Comment: I can replicate the issue too. I'm running  `R 3.5.0 (2018-04-23) 64-bit`, SO: `Windows 10 pro`

Comment: Are you running in Rstudio vs the basic R GUI? If so, Rstudio makes references to variables. Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48230311/copy-on-modify-semantic-on-a-vector-does-not-append-in-a-loop-why/48230836#48230836

Comment: @MrFlick I am using Rstudio. But now I tested on the R console and I can replicate the issue here too.

Comment: I can only replicate in RStudio. In R console the address stays the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a [change in how R 3.5 stores values in the form `a:b`](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2018/04/r-350.html). If you try the same example with

```
library(pryr)
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
address(x)
x[2] <- 7L
address(x)
```

You should get the same address. Now the `1:10` isn't full expanded until it has to be. And changing an element inside the vector will cause it to expand.