# Stop copy-on-modify behavior in R in a while loop

Tags: r, vector, memory-efficient

I'm doing a rejection sampling on R that needs to be as efficient as possible. Here is my raw code :

```
N <- 1e8
x <- rexp(N, 3) + rexp(N, 3)
todo <- runif(N, -1, 1) < cos(3.2*pi*x)

while(any(todo)){
  x[todo] <- rexp(sum(todo), 3) + rexp(sum(todo), 3)
  todo[todo] <- runif(sum(todo), -1, 1) < cos(3.2*pi*x[todo])
}
```

I was reading about copy-and-modify on https://adv-r.hadley.nz/names-values.html, and decided to use the lobstr package to find if there was any object concerned (with the `tracemem()` function), and lo-and-behold, the logical vector `todo` keeps getting copied in the while loop !

If I do the following test :

```
library(lobstr)
N <- 1e8
x <- rexp(N, 3) + rexp(N, 3)
todo <- runif(N, -1, 1) < cos(3.2*pi*x)
cat(tracemem(todo), "\n")

while(any(todo)){
  x[todo] <- rexp(sum(todo), 3) + rexp(sum(todo), 3)
  todo[todo] <- runif(sum(todo), -1, 1) < cos(3.2*pi*x[todo])
}
```

I get the following result (confirming my worries) :

```
[1] "0x38f4938"
[1] "0x1959ff30"
[1] "0x38f4938"
[1] "0x173bb6f0"
[1] "0x38f4938"
[1] "0x4caf788"
[1] "0x38f4938"
[1] "0x1a801628"
[1] "0x38f4938"
[1] "0x18f36768"
[1] "0x38f4938"
[1] "0x4e4d478"
[1] "0x38f4938"
[1] "0x195b93d8"
[1] "0x38f4938"
[1] "0x3f59fe0"
[1] "0x38f4938"
[1] "0x45ebf40"
[1] "0x38f4938"
[1] "0x1a42bdd8"
[1] "0x38f4938"
[1] "0x16c72ba0"
```

Can someone please help me get rid of this time-consuming behavior ? I tried, without success, the following declarations :

1. `todo <- logical(N)`
2. `todo <- list(logical(N))`

Edit : also, any help with improving the time efficiency of this bottleneck in my code will be very much appreciated...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48230311/copy-on-modify-semantic-on-a-vector-does-not-append-in-a-loop-why. I think the problem is that the random number functions are not primitive functions.

Comment: I think the main issue is that during the subset assignment you index the vector with itself. You can reproduce this with `todo <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE); tracemem(todo); todo[todo] <- c(TRUE, FALSE)`. If you consider [how subset assignment is implemented](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Subset-assignment), the copy isn't really surprising. Maybe it would be possible to avoid the copy if you implement this step in C++ using Rcpp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's possible for base R, but you can optimise this procedure using the `data.table` package. Try this and you will see no copy is made (I also did some other minor changes to further optimise your code)

```
library(data.table)

N <- 1e7; i <- 1:N
dt <- list(x = double(N), todo = logical(N)); setDT(dt)
cat(tracemem(dt), "\n")
cat(tracemem(N), "\n")
cat(tracemem(i), "\n")

while(N > 0L){
  set(dt, i, "x", rexp(N, 3) + rexp(N, 3))
  set(dt, i, "todo", runif(N, -1, 1) < cos(3.2*pi*dt[i]$x))
  N <- length(i <- which(dt$todo))
}
```

It takes about 3 seconds to run, which is a bit too long. I think there is room for further improvement.

```
system.time({
  N <- 1e7; i <- 1:N
  dt <- list(x = double(N), todo = logical(N)); setDT(dt)
  
  while(N > 0L){
    set(dt, i, "x", rexp(N, 3) + rexp(N, 3))
    set(dt, i, "todo", runif(N, -1, 1) < cos(3.2*pi*dt[i]$x))
    N <- length(i <- which(dt$todo))
  }
})
```

Result

```
 user  system elapsed 
 3.26    0.10    3.34
```

Comment: Thank you ! My code is significantly faster now :)