# R pass-by-value or pass-by-reference

Tags: r, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

if i create a function in R, for example:

```
f<-function(x){
x
.....

}
```

when execute function R use pass-by-value or pass-by-reference

Comment: https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/intermediate-r/chapter-3-functions?ex=13

Comment: neither.  It's "copy-on-modify", i.e. it generates a new value if necessary.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759117/what-exactly-is-copy-on-modify-semantics-in-r-and-where-is-the-canonical-source

Answer (score -1):

```
In R it is call by value. To prove this i tried with a small function as below;

f1 <- function(a,b){

  print(a)

  #print b value before call
  print(b)

  fi(b)
  #print b value after call
  print(b)

}

fi <- function(i){
   i = i + 20
}

f1(10,20)

output :
----------
[1] 10
[1] 20
[1] 20
```