# Mutable 'list-like object in R?

Tags: r

I want to create a list `x` in R, containing entries, say like `red = 32, green = 34` and so on. Suppose I have the function `func` which takes in `x` and changes `red = 32` to `red = 23`. I then want to call `func(x)` and *have that modify `x`,* so of I then query `x` I get the updated version. How do I get such an object in R?

Comment: You can do this easily. But you should not. What you describe is called a site effect and we are trying to avoid site effects in R. Learn functional programming instead.

Comment: R usually uses [call-by-value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15759117/1412059). However, you can (using C/C++ code) also do call-by-reference. The data.table package is an example for this. It's also easy to implement with Rcpp (for pretty much any object). Is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are asking for is this function :

```
wrong_func <- function(list_data, name, value) {
   list_data[[name]] <<- value
}
list_data <- list(red = 32, green = 34)
list_data$red
#[1] 32

wrong_func(list_data, "red", 23)
list_data$red
#[1] 23
```

However, this is incorrect way to do this and should be avoided. Instead do :

```
right_func <- function(list_data, name, value) {
   list_data[[name]] <- value
   list_data
}
list_data <- list(red = 32, green = 34)
list_data$red
#[1] 32
list_data <- right_func(list_data, "red", 23)
list_data$red
#[1] 23
```

Comment: I should have been clearer. I'm not looking for the function. Suppose ```right_func``` is given as you have it. What kinds of objects ```list_data``` are mutable? If I know that calling```right_func(list_data)``` and then ```list_data$red``` gives 23, *what was* ```list_data```?

Comment: @sasannjuj `list_data` is a `list`, which is a mutable list object in R. However, R is not a strictly typed language, so Ronak's solution would work if `list_data` was any class for which the subsetting operators `[[` and `$` are defined.

Comment: What I'd like to see is ```right_func(list_data)``` *modifying the value* of ```list_data```, not the assignment. I agree this is the correct and standard way of doing the same thing, but I'm asking about the kind of data structure on ```list_data``` permitting this.

Comment: @sasannjuj Isn't that what `wrong_func(list_data, "red", 23)` already does?

Comment: Yes, ```wrong_func``` does do this. My question is however the following: given ```right_func``` as you write it, assign a data structure to ```x``` such that if I type ```right_func(x)``` and then ```x$red``` I get 23 and not 32.

Comment: I don't understand your question. One function behaves according to the way you want, another does not. Then use the function which behaves according to your requirement or if name is the problem you can rename it. `right_func <- wrong_func`