# Unexpected memory address allocation in lapply function in R

Tags: r, list, memory-address

I recently was on a bug hunt and made an observation that you can reproduce with the following lines of code:

```r
library(lobstr)
lapply(1:10, function(g){
 record <- list(EK = rep(1,1))
 lobstr::obj_addr(record$EK)
})

lapply(1:10, function(g){
 record <- list(EK = 1)
 lobstr::obj_addr(record$EK)
})
```

Essentially, I am creating a variable called record which contains a list with a single element. In the one case I am setting this variable (`EK`) to be 1 and in the other I am doing the same but using `rep(1,1)`.

When looking at the memory location (using the `lobstr` package) I find that in the case of setting `EK = 1`, all record variables have the same memory location, whereas those set with `rep(1,1)` have each their own memory location. This is the code with the output:

```r
> lapply(1:10, function(g){
+  record <- list(EK = rep(1,1))
+  lobstr::obj_addr(record$EK)
+ })
[[1]]
[1] "0x7f9ff4bc3c20"

[[2]]
[1] "0x7f9ff4c8e668"

[[3]]
[1] "0x7f9ff4c8e438"

[[4]]
[1] "0x7f9ff4c8e208"

[[5]]
[1] "0x7f9ff4c8dfd8"

[[6]]
[1] "0x7f9ff4c8dda8"

[[7]]
[1] "0x7f9ff4c8db78"

[[8]]
[1] "0x7f9ff4c8d948"

[[9]]
[1] "0x7f9ff4c8d718"

[[10]]
[1] "0x7f9ff4c8d4e8"

> 
> lapply(1:10, function(g){
+  record <- list(EK = 1)
+  lobstr::obj_addr(record$EK)
+ })
[[1]]
[1] "0x7f9ff4ca3190"

[[2]]
[1] "0x7f9ff4ca3190"

[[3]]
[1] "0x7f9ff4ca3190"

[[4]]
[1] "0x7f9ff4ca3190"

[[5]]
[1] "0x7f9ff4ca3190"

[[6]]
[1] "0x7f9ff4ca3190"

[[7]]
[1] "0x7f9ff4ca3190"

[[8]]
[1] "0x7f9ff4ca3190"

[[9]]
[1] "0x7f9ff4ca3190"

[[10]]
[1] "0x7f9ff4ca3190"
```

The actual bug in my code (receiving the same output on repeated runs of the same simulation code in an `mclapply()` call) turned out not be caused by this (I thought it was because R used the same memory location, if that is actually the case) but by how the random number generator was initialised.

Still, I am curious. From the help file of `?obj_addr()` I understand that "the address of an object is different every time you create it". So, why then does the one method create different memory addresses and the other doesn't?

Comment: Hmm … why wouldn’t it be? Even just seeing the initial code this was the behaviour I’d intuitively expect: a literal always has the same address, and each newly created vector has a distinct address.

Comment: Have a look at: [What exactly is copy-on-modify semantics in R, and where is the canonical source?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15759117/10488504)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Konrad, I did not know that. I assumed that every item get's its own place somewhere in memory. But I see now, if I change what is stored in each iteration of `lapply()`, the memory address will be different in either case:

```r
library(lobstr)
lapply(1:10, function(g){
 record <- list(EK = rep(1,1))
 record$EK<-round(runif(1,0,1)*10)
 lobstr::obj_addr(record$EK)
})

lapply(1:10, function(g){
 record <- list(EK = 1)
 record$EK<-round(runif(1,0,1)*10)
 lobstr::obj_addr(record$EK)
})
```

Okay, so I can take that off my list to worry about. Thanks again for the fast reply.